# How can I tell the dart editor to show all files in project folder?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

More specifically I have a .gitignore file that was generated when I made my project directory a git repository. That file doesn't show up in the dart editor. I'm assuming it is because of the `.` prepending the name. I looked around briefly in the menus and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible at the moment, how about creating a feature request at http://dartbug.com/new ?

Comment: @Fox32 Thanks for the suggestion I opened it here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced bug is marked as NotPlanned; so it seems support will not be added to Dart Editor.

The good news is that [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en), which seems to be where Google are putting a lot of their effort for an IDE does show these files fine. Note: CDE is still in preview and doesn't have half of the functionality of Dart Editor (yet).